# select dynamically added element with jquery...

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically added an element in page using jquery with following function.

```
function addtocart(popid)
{
    jQuery('#thumb'+popid+' button').attr("disabled", true);
    //jQuery('#thumb'+popid+' button').html("Added");
    position = jQuery('#cart').offset();
    source = jQuery('#thumb'+popid+' img').offset();

    jQuery('#thumb'+popid+' img').clone().css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute','top':source.top,'left':source.left}).appendTo('body').addClass('animation');
    jQuery('.animation').animate(
        {'left': position.left, 'top':position.top},
        'slow',
        function(){
                jQuery(this).remove();
                jQuery('#cart').append('<li class="test">'+jQuery('#thumb'+popid+' .title').html()+'<a href="#">X</a></li>');
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "creatives.php?ajax=1&creativeid="+popid,
                    success:function(data){
                        jQuery('.itemstodwnload span').html(data);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        );
}
```

but i cannot call any event on this new element.

```
jQuery('.test').hover(function(){
            alert('asdf');
        });
```

any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you set the event handler by doing

```
jQuery('.test').hover(function(){
            alert('asdf');
        });
```

you're doing just once (the browser set that function as event handler for all the object with "test" class present at the time of executing this line. To have an handler setted for every "test" element, you should use intead

```
jQuery('.test').live('hover', function(){
            alert('asdf');
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to attach events to elements added to the DOM after page loading.

try

```
jQuery('.test').live('hover', function(){
            alert('asdf');
        });
```

This is because events are attached to elements usually when DOM it's ready and if you add elements afterwards they have no events attached. Live() uses event bubbling to work around this.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
jQuery(".test").live({
    mouseenter:
       function()
       {

       },
    mouseleave:
       function()
       {

       }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

to bind an event on dynamically created element, jquery provides fallowing two functions to acomplish this-

1. [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
2. [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

you can use `delegate` in same way as i have used `live`

```
jQuery('.test').live('hover', function(){             
              alert('asdf');        
     });
```

Advantage of delegate over live is that you can do chaining in delegate but not in hover.